# 2 Different Owl Carousel Sliders on one page with different width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, owl-carousel

I recently came across Owl Carousel. I tried using 2 sliders of different widths within a page.

I am using the bootstrap grid system. I faced 2 main problems using Owl Carousel:

1. While using `Container-fluid` instead of Owl Carousel's `container`, a small portion of another image is shown in the left and right side. How do I deal with this?

Owl Carousel jQuery:

```
$('#main-slider').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            nav: true,
            autoplay:true,
            lazyLoad:true,
            singleItem: true,
            slideSpeed : 300,
            paginationSpeed : 400,
            items : 1, 
            itemsDesktop : false,
            itemsDesktopSmall : false,
            itemsTablet: false,
            itemsMobile : false,
            dots: false,
            responsiveClass:true,
            navText: ["&#8592;","&#8594;"]
        });
```

HTML for Owl Carousel:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="main-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<img  class=" " src="./images/slider-banner01.jpg" alt="" />
<img  class=" " src="./images/slider-banner02.jpg" alt="" />
<img  class=" " src="./images/slider-banner03.jpg" alt="" />
<img  class=" " src="./images/slider-banner04.jpg" alt="" />
<img  class=" " src="./images/slider-banner05.jpg" alt="" />
<img  class=" " src="./images/slider-banner06.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
```

2. I want one banner slider and one another slider to display a Brand's logo which I want to place within a `col-md-4` class of bootstrap.
   However, even if I place it under `col-md-4` the slider still takes the full device width.

Owl Carousel jQuery:

```
$('#main-brand-slider').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:false,
            autoplay:true,
            lazyLoad:true,
            items : 1, 
            itemsDesktop : false,
            itemsDesktopSmall : false,
            itemsTablet: false,
            itemsMobile : false,
            dots: false,
        });
```

HTML for Brand Slider:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="section-text text-center">
<h3>Brands</h3>
<div class="container">
<div id="main-brand-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<img class="img-responsive" src="./images/brandsSlider1.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="./images/brandsSlider2.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="./images/brandsSlider3.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="./images/brandsSlider4.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="./images/brandsSlider5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `padding-left:0px;` and `padding-right:0px;` with `container-fluid` because `container-fluid` has default `padding-left:15px;` and `padding-right:15px;`

**Brand Slider Issue**
You need to remove `container` class that is inside `col-md-4` because `container` has default `width:1170px;`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/dpnta0z9/

```js
$('#main-slider').owlCarousel({ 
 loop:true, 
  nav: true, 
  autoplay:true, 
  lazyLoad:true, 
  singleItem: true, 
  slideSpeed : 300, 
  paginationSpeed : 400, 
  items : 2, 
  itemsDesktop : false, 
  itemsDesktopSmall : false, 
  itemsTablet: false, 
  itemsMobile : false, 
  dots: false, 
  responsiveClass:true, 
  navText: ["←","→"] 
});

$('#main-brand-slider').owlCarousel({ loop:true, margin:10, nav:false, autoplay:true, lazyLoad:true, items : 1, itemsDesktop : false, itemsDesktopSmall : false, itemsTablet: false, itemsMobile : false, dots: false, });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="main-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <img  class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
        <img  class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
        <img  class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
        <img  class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
        <img  class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
        <img  class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="section-text text-center">
        <h3>Brands</h3>
        <div id="main-brand-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150g" alt="" />
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this will help you.